# Python: How do I examine the predicted rows in y_pred?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

My logistic regression algorithm returned y_pred as an array. Example:

```
array([False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False,
       False, False, ...])
```

I would like to see which rows in the data set were predicted as True. As a sanity test so to speak, to see if the wrongly predicted True's were absolute wrong or at least close. Is there a way to get the index for the predicted rows? Or any other way how this is usually done?

Comment: What you are looking for seems to be this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

Comment: The order of the predicted values is same as the array you passed on input to do the prediction.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski does that mean I have to individually examine the rows? Or does python offer a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your prediction is:

```
y = array([False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, ...])
```

Then the data behind will be simply:

```
data[y]
```

assuming prediction was made on `data`.

Example:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = datasets.load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True) # 2 classes - binary classification
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
prediction = knn.predict(X_test).astype(bool)
```

In the last step we take advantage of two facts:

- `X` and `y` have the same sequence order. Running `predict` preserves the order
- Selecting array items with boolean condition

```
pred_tested_true = X_test[prediction]
```

`pred_tested_true` now contains all rows that were predicted as `True`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this by comparing and segregating the predictions & actuals as TP, FP (which is what u are looking for as I understand), TN, FN.

You can do that by -

```
y_pred = [True, False, True, False]
y_actual = [True, True, False, True]

#This gets you the indexes
FP = [i[0] for i in enumerate(zip(y_pred, y_actual)) if i[1]==(False, True)] 

#Change the tuple to what you need, for false positives, its y_pred, y_actual = False, True

#You can do a loc if you need after this
df.loc[FP,:]
```